# Keyboard shortcut for switching between different keyboard layouts in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: keyboard-layout, shortcuts, mate

Is there a pre-assigned keyboard shortcut for switching between different keyboard layouts in Ubuntu Mate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there is no pre-assigned shortcut.

You can choose from many options to assign a shortcut to switch layouts from the menu:

**Keyboard Preferences > Layouts**

[image]

This menu can be found under **System > Preferences > Hardware**

Comment: I always thought Alt+Shift is the only way to change the layout.. Now this is good :D

Comment: Ok this is a broken feature.. Other keyboard shortcuts stop working if you're using a  key that's used to in a sequence to change layouts. For example I use "Winkey + Right" to move to right workspace and it doesn't work anymore because now I'm switching layouts with my Winkey..

Answer (score 4):

### Quick answer:

1. Right click on language icon and select **Keyboard Preferences**.
2. In **Layouts** tab --> click **Options...** .
3. Expand **Switching to another layouts**.
4. Select <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut or other options.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal
2. Type:
   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"`
3. Switch languages with **Alt + Shift_left**

Answer (score 0):

The pre-assigned shortcuts are <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

<sub><kbd>SUPER</kbd> generally means the Window key.</sub>