# 18.04 Mate switch language with "Alt+Shift" error

Tags: 18.04, mate, input-language

Following the solution provided in post [Keyboard shortcut for switching between different keyboard layouts in Ubuntu Mate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801006/keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-between-different-keyboard-layouts-in-ubuntu-mat)
I get the "Error activating XKB configuration", see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldJWc.png).

[Screenshot of setxkbmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtJrq.png)

Comment: If you use Ubuntu MATE, do it the Ubuntu MATE way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut for switching between different keyboard layouts in Ubuntu Mate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801006/keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-between-different-keyboard-layouts-in-ubuntu-mat)

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying and I keep getting the error. Despite the error the setting is stored and now the error message pops up consistently during login. Actually in the top panel 2 language indicators have appeared. One toggles between languages with Alt+Shift, the other not, however the shortcut does not work, the keyvoard changes to Greek only with the mouse. I should add also that when logging in with Gnome, Alt+Shift works after using the solution provided in the post.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the answer to the question you pointed at includes a MATE part. Maybe it's a MATE bug. It would be interesting to know what happens if you try some other shortcut via the MATE GUI.

Comment: MATE GUI you mean "MATE Control Center/Keyboard/Layout/Options/Switching to another layout" ? This is what I have done and got the error message.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to suggest that you try some **other** shortcut, i.e. something else but <Alt>+<Shift>.

Comment: I tried several, same error message.

Comment: Hmm.. What does the command `setxkbmap -query -v 10` output? And also, the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard`? Please copy the terminal output, edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: Done, screenshot with the output added.